# Gyroscope data is the same for x and y axis, how to fix?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm programming an altimeter with an arduino.

I'm having some issues with the accuracy of the change in height and figuring out how to set off the pyrocharges when the rocket starts to fall. Also I have an issue with the gyroscope data, it gives me the same exact data for the x and y axis. I also need for someone to look over my code in general. Parts of my code are based on code I found on the internet.

This code is for the altimeter for my high school's rocket which will be going to 56323 meters in the air and has taken my class a year to finish and so I'm deciding whether to just use the arduino I've programmed to set of the pyrocharges or to use a stratologger and just use the arduino as a datalogger.

I'm using the Arduino Geniuno Uno, an MPU-6000 (gyroscope and accelerometer) and MS5611 (barometer) .

```
//imports Library
#include <Wire.h>

//The variables for the gyroscope
float elapsedTime, time, timePrev; // these are time 
int gyro_error =0;// used to calculate error
float Gyro_rawX, Gyro_rawY, Gyro_rawZ; //the raw angle data
float angleX, angleY;
float Gyro_raw_errorX, Gyro_raw_errorY;
float Total_angle_x, Total_angle_y;


void setup(){

  //starting up the I2C device
  Wire.begin();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);//This starts the transmission to the I2C device, while most things online will tell you that it's 0x68 it's not
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0x00);//reset
  Wire.endTransmission(true);//end Transmission

  //Gyroscope configuration
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);
  Wire.write(0x1B);
  Wire.write(0x10);//for the gyroscope use 0x10 for the accelerometer use 0x18
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  Serial.begin(9600);//for this we are using a 9600 baud rate
  time = millis();

//This gets the data for the gyroscope
if(gyro_error==0)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
      Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);            //begin, Send the slave adress (in this case 68) 
      Wire.write(0x43);                        //First adress of the Gyro data
      Wire.endTransmission(false);
      Wire.requestFrom(0x69,4,true);           //We ask for just 4 registers 

      Gyro_rawX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();     //Once again we shif and sum
      Gyro_rawY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();

      /*---X---*/
      Gyro_raw_errorX = Gyro_raw_errorX + (Gyro_rawX/32.8); 
      /*---Y---*/
      Gyro_raw_errorY = Gyro_raw_errorY + (Gyro_rawY/32.8);

 if(i==199)
      {
        Gyro_raw_errorX = Gyro_raw_errorX/200;
        Gyro_raw_errorY = Gyro_raw_errorY/200;
        gyro_error=1;
      }
    }
  }


  //beeper just to know if it's working
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(400);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(400);

  }


  void loop(){
    timePrev =time;
    time= millis();
    elapsedTime = (time - timePrev)/1000;

   //Gyroscope
   Wire.beginTransmission(0x69);
   Wire.write(0x43);
   Wire.endTransmission(false);
   Wire.requestFrom(0x69,6,true);

    Gyro_rawX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();     
    Gyro_rawY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();

    Gyro_rawX = (Gyro_rawX/32.8) - Gyro_raw_errorX; 

    Gyro_rawY = (Gyro_rawY/32.8) - Gyro_raw_errorY;

    angleX = Gyro_rawX * elapsedTime;

    angleY = Gyro_rawX * elapsedTime; 

    Total_angle_x = 0.98 *(Total_angle_x + angleX) + 0.02*Accel_angleX;

    Total_angle_y = 0.98 *(Total_angle_y + angleY) + 0.02*Accel_angleY;


    //This prints out rotation
    Serial.print("X rotation");//in the x axis
    Serial.println(Total_angle_x,4);
    Serial.print("Y rotation");//in the y axis
    Serial.println(Total_angle_y,4);


      }
```

The data that is printed out in the serial monitor for the x and y axis is exactly the same like `x=1.0302`, `y=1.0302`. The other problem is that if I change the angle and put it back down the it won't go back to zero.

Comment: For working code https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate.

Comment: I doubt anyone's going to read through and debug that code, here or on code review. The good news is that "I'm having some issues with the accuracy of the change in height" and "Also I have an issue with the gyroscope data, it gives me the same exact data for the x and y axis" both sound like great problems for a debugger. I'm sure if try to distil your problems down into seperate questions with [mcve]s, that people will be more inclined to help. But I think you'd be better off debugging the code yourself in this case.

Comment: Some abstractions are missing, split in sub-function, add classes. Avoid magic numbers (name them only once as const global, and refer them with their name).

Comment: This looks like a job for code review.

Comment: Okay thank you, I didn't know about code review, I'll change my question to just ask about the gyroscope.